# What are enterprise applications?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am a java developer who is new to Java EE. To start with, I want to understand why we need all the enterprise applications when we already have massive frameworks for building the web.

I gathered that Java EE is the web-based side of Java. So, why does Java need one when there are other web methods out there?

I might be totally wrong, that is why I am asking for enlightenment in this area. A simple  explanation of a scenario where Java EE is needed will clarify my confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many competitors in the web framework space. Java, and specifically Java EE is just one of those. It's a very popular and well known one, but there's also e.g. ASP.NET/C# which can be used to build approximately the same (web) applications with slightly other advantages and disadvantages.

When you ask `why does Java need one when there are other web methods out there?`, you're basically asking "why is their competition in this world"?

Why does Opel need to make a car, when there are already other car manufacturers out there?